# An unparenthesized arithmetic expression

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, dynamic-programming

An arithmetic expression can have many possible values

Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you looking for a specific language? You will have to build a for loop and iterate through the possible combinations. You will need a variable to track the highest sum outcome. Each iteration you will check the answer against the tracking variable and replace it if it is greater.

Comment: pseudo code, I believe this is done by dynamic programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a dynamic programming solution.

For a expression, you can define its "outmost split point" be the first operator that is not within any parentheses. Now after this split, if it is on a `+`, then you need to maximize the left sub expression and the right sub expression; if it is a `-`, then maximize the left side and minimize the right side.

You can use either dynamic programming or memoization to implement this algorithm. Memoization is straightforward: search for each split point, and save the answer in another data structure (two 2D matrices, with `M[x][y]` string the max/min value of the expression beginning at `x` and ending at `y`); when the data is in the matrices, use it instead of recompute.

Use dynamic programming is a bit trickier, but you can think of it this way:

1. first, you loop through the expression, finding the max/min for each consecutive 2 values with the operator between them (well, this is the fancy way of saying just compute it);
2. loop through the expression, finding the max/min for each consecutive 3 values with the operator between them (for `a ? b ? c`, this is computed by assuming the split point is between `a` and `b`, and the assuming the split point is on `b` and `c`, and store the max/min values of these two);
3. Once you know the max/min for all `k`-length sequences, compute the `k + 1`-length ones using the same method as in step 2, until k is the length of the array, and return the max value for length `k`.

This is almost the same as [Matrix Chain Multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication) algorithm, which has `O(N^3)` complexity. The complexity can be proved crudely by reasoning: you need to do the loop `N - 1` times, each time at most `N - 1` subsequences, and you need to try at most `N - 1` split points. So, `N ^ 3` time complexity.